# Current Workgroup

Tags: samba

I would like to get the current workgroup of my Linux machine. When I google it, I get only methods to set or rename the workgroup. I found a command `hostname` but that returns only my PC name as username-desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking for the Windows Workgroup that your computer is, you might have success with `smbclient -L localhost -N`.

On the last line of the output this gives the workgroup name and the name of the workgroup's master (a Linux system using Samba system in my case):

```
    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP            OWL
```

Comment: I am new to Linux. Linux systems have a workgroup like 
Windows systems do right? I want to get that name. Will the samba client be installed in every Linux system by default?

Comment: @Parthe No, the workgroup is a Windows artifact. In my case I allow windows machines to access my Linux server system using the SMB/CIFS protocol, implemented by the **optional** Samba software (optional on Linux).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So there is no guarantee that Samba will be installed in every Linux machine. Workgroups don't exist in Linux. Am I right? I will try and let you know if the above command worked.

Comment: @Parthe That is correct, there is no guarantee it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but my Unraid server returns with `smbclient` this error message (although SMB1 is enabled and a workgroup is set):

```
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Because of that I came up with reading the workgroup value of smb.conf as follows

```
testparm -sl --parameter-name=workgroup 2>/dev/null
```

returns:

```
WORKGROUP
```

Used options:

```
-s, --suppress-prompt           Suppress prompt for enter
-l, --skip-logic-checks         Skip the global checks
    --parameter-name=STRING     Limit testparm to a named parameter
```

Comment: Indeed. SMB1 is obsolete, and workgroups these days aren't really far off either